# a bug from rpc call to other node?

Tags: scala, go, erlang, elixir

i created 2 erlang nodes in the same Windows machine with two cmd windows:'unclient@MYPC' and 'unserveur@MYPC' , the server code is very simple :

```
-module(serveur).
-export([start/0,recever/0,inverse/1]). 
%%%%
start() ->
Pid=spawn(serveur,recever,[]), 
register(ownServer, Pid). 
%%%%
recever() -> 
receive 
{From, X} ->From ! {ownServer,1/X} end. 
%%%%
inverse(X) -> 
ownServer!{self(),1/X}
 receive
{ownServer, Reply} ->Reply end.
```

so at the server node cmd i start this module

```
c(serveur). 
serveur:start()
```

at the client node i used the rpc call function to try the connection and all is fine, for example i try :

```
rpc:call(unserveur@MYPC,serveur,inverse,[2]).
```

and i received 0.5 
now i use an atom to send it to the server for causing an error

```
rpc:call(unserveur@MYPC,serveur,inverse,[a]).
```

at the client cmd node :
i waited for the response from the server but i didn't receive anything and there is no more the client prompt :

```
unclient@MYPC 1>
```

i can write but the shell does not execute my instructions anymore and there is not any prompt.

I searched about and i found that `rpc:call` trigger the rex server at the destination node to spawns  and monitors a process who execute the (M,F,A) is that true ? if yes why i had this bug on the client node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On unclient side, `rpc:call(Node,serveur,inverse,[a])` builds a message for the Node rpc server and wait a response.

on unserveur side, the RPC server receives the message and start a process to call the function `serveur:inverse(a)`.

the `inverse` function send a message to the `serveur:recever()` which execute the instruction `1/a` and crashes.

Therefore, the reply message cannot be sent back to inverse. The inverse function will wait the answer forever, as well as the rpc:call on unclient node since you did not define any timeout.

You could define a time out in the inverse function:

```
inverse(X) -> 
    ownServer!{self(),1/X}
    receive
        {ownServer, Reply} -> {ok,Reply} 
    after 100 -> % define a timout of 100 ms
        {error,timeout}
    end.
```

In addition, it is a good idea to use a timeout in the remote procedure call using `rpc:call(Node, Module, Function, Args, Timeout)`

In a previous post you were trying to get a response using the trap_exit flag. There were several mistakes there. First as explained by @legoscia, in case of error, the exit message is sent to any linked process. The second is that you were expecting that your process will continue to execute its code. On error, the process stops immediately and the system issues the exit message which kills or will be received by all the linked process depending on the flag trap_exit value.

I wrote a version that works as you expected:

```
-module(serveur).
-export([start/0,recever/0,inverse/1]). 
-export([do_op/3]).

%%%%
start() -> 
    Pid=spawn(serveur,recever,[]), 
    register(ownServer, Pid). 

%%%%
recever() -> 
    process_flag(trap_exit,true), 
    receive
        stop -> stopped;
        {'EXIT',_,_} -> recever(); % necessary to throw the {EXIT,_,normal} messages
        {From, Op, X} -> 
            spawn_link(serveur, do_op, [self(),Op,X]),
            receive 
                Reply -> From ! {ownServer, Reply}  
            end,
            recever()
    end. 

do_op(From, inverse, X) ->
    From ! {result,1/X}.

%%%%
inverse(X) -> 
    ownServer!{self(), inverse, X}, 
    receive 
        {ownServer, Reply} ->Reply 
    end.
```

In fact this code works more or less like a `catch` statement, which is exactly what you wanted to do, and it is what you should use there. In erlang, it is a very good idea to let processes crash when something unexpected happens, specially using the Erlang OTP mechanisms, but when the error is probable (user interface for example) I think it is more adapted to use catch or try/catch at the right level.

**[edit]**

It is cool that you want to fully understand the behavior of the system. To answer to your question, I am sorry but I never use rpc, and I don't know in which cases it is well suited.

For this case I use the global library that allow the communication between the nodes of a cluster (see [erlang distribution from learnyousomeerlang a very good site to learn and understand erlang](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon#rpc)).

As you say the way you solved the issue use a lot of code (and I am not sure that it works in local now). In my opinion, it is because the flag trap_exit is not meant for this usage but for the OTP supervisor trees and all the otp behaviors (see [What is OTP from the same site](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/what-is-otp)). In your case, you should use a catch statement and add timeouts to handle the possible errors. Here is a code which handle bad arguments and overloaded server. I have added a few interfaces to simulate the different use cases.

```
-module(serveur).

-export([start/0,recever/0,inverse/1,lock/0,unlock/0,stop/0,wait10s/0]). 

%%%%
start() ->
    Pid=spawn(serveur,recever,[]), 
    register(ownServer, Pid). 

%%%%
recever() -> 
    receive 
        {From, X} ->
            From ! {ownServer,(catch 1/X)},
            recever();
        waitForUnlock ->
            ok = wait_for_unlock(),
            recever();
        stop -> server_stopped
    end.

%%%%
inverse(X) -> 
    ownServer ! {self(),X},
    receive
        {ownServer, {'EXIT',{Reply,_}}} ->
            {error,Reply};      
        {ownServer, Reply} ->
            {ok,Reply}
    after 100 ->
        {error,timeout}
    end.

%%%% use this interface to simulate an overloaded server 
lock() ->
    ownServer ! waitForUnlock.

%%%% use this interface to unlock the server
unlock() ->
    ownServer ! unlock.

%%%% use this interface to simulate a very long answer from server
wait10s() ->
    timer:sleep(10000),
    iAmAwake.

%%%% use this interface to stop the server
stop() ->
    ownServer ! stop.

%%%% private function used to hang the server
wait_for_unlock() ->
    receive
        unlock -> ok
    end.
```

The test on local node

```
(unserveur@MyPc)1> c(serveur).
{ok,serveur}
(unserveur@MyPc)2> serveur:start().
true
(unserveur@MyPc)3> serveur:inverse(2).
{ok,0.5}
(unserveur@MyPc)4> serveur:inverse(a).
{error,badarith}
(unserveur@MyPc)5> serveur:lock().   
waitForUnlock
(unserveur@MyPc)6> serveur:inverse(2).
{error,timeout}
(unserveur@MyPc)7> serveur:inverse(a).
{error,timeout}
(unserveur@MyPc)8> serveur:unlock().  
unlock
(unserveur@MyPc)9> serveur:inverse(2).
{ok,0.5}
(unserveur@MyPc)10> serveur:wait10s(). 
iAmAwake
(unserveur@MyPc)11> serveur:stop().   
stop
(unserveur@MyPc)12> serveur:inverse(2).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  serveur:inverse/1 (serveur.erl, line 60)
(unserveur@MyPc)13>
```

and (almost) the same test from the client node

```
(unclient@MyPc)1> net_adm:ping(unserveur@MyPc).
pong
(unclient@MyPc)2> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,start,[]).
true
(unclient@MyPc)3> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,inverse,[2]).
{ok,0.5}
(unclient@MyPc)4> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,inverse,[a]).
{error,badarith}
(unclient@MyPc)5> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,lock,[]).    
waitForUnlock
(unclient@MyPc)6> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,inverse,[2]).
{error,timeout}
(unclient@MyPc)7> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,inverse,[a]).
{error,timeout}
(unclient@MyPc)8> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,unlock,[]).  
unlock
(unclient@MyPc)9> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,inverse,[2]).
{ok,0.5}
(unclient@MyPc)10> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,wait10s,[]). 
iAmAwake
(unclient@MyPc)11> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,wait10s,[],1000).
{badrpc,timeout}
(unclient@MyPc)12> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,stop,[]).        
stop
(unclient@MyPc)13> rpc:call(unserveur@MyPc,serveur,inverse,[2]).    
{badrpc,{'EXIT',{badarg,[{serveur,inverse,1,
                                  [{file,"serveur.erl"},{line,60}]},
                         {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                              [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,197}]}]}}}
(unclient@MyPc)14>
```

Comment: thank you pascal, all that you said is true so i used something in the place of the timoeout i add ```process_flag(trap_exit, true), link(ownServer)```at the head of the inverse function and i add in the receive section ```{'EXIT',_, _} ->apply(serveur, start, []).``` That make the rex process who run inverse trapping the exit of the serveur:recever process and he can restart it but that didn't work and i had the same error, how can you explain that ? and thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, Finally i resolved this bug and the most important i understood what happens :
when i called `rpc:call('unserveur@MYPC',serveur,inverse,[a])` the client node process(the main shell process) send this message to the serveur node process(the main shell process) , the serveur node process send this message to the rex server of the serveur node, the rex server spawns and monitors a new process who will run `apply(serveur, inverse, [a])`, this new process run the function and the serveur process who run `recever()` will crash and no reply to the new process who will wait forever and all the processes behind him will wait forever including the main shell client  node process and that explains the desapearing of the prompt and writing normally. This is exactely what Pascal said so you have answered my question.
i resolved this problem by adding

```
process_flag(trap_exit, true),
link(whereis(ownServer)),
```

at the head of the `inverse` function and i add

```
{'EXIT', _, _} -> start(),
                         sorry;
```

at the head of the `receive` session of the `inverse` function and when i called the rpc call with an atom i can see sorry at the client node shell and the server returns automatically to work again so when i called for the second time rpc call inverse with an integer i had the right answer.
i see that i coded a lot for this call so may be the rpc call is  not a good choice and replacing it with spawning processes manually will be better, what do you think ?

Comment: very good, I edited my post to answer (more or less) your last question.

Comment: thank you Pascal i see that you resolved the bug with catch statement and this is good but why Joe recommended erlang programmers to not using defensive programming and replace it with ' let't it crash' ? and if you can give me just a little example of supervisor and worker tree because in books i see just the concept without clear example

Comment: In my understanding, we can splits errors in 2 categories: the one which are probable, very often because of human interaction, the one which are unexpected due to failure or bug. For the first category, I think that defensive programming is ok, because when you write the program you know what are the human inputs, and if you send back an appropriate message, the user will be able to correct the input. In your case, the best place to put a check is in the inverse function so you do not disturb the server (for example `inverse(X) when is_number(X), not(X == 0)  -> ...`

Comment: For the second kind of error, you don't know what and where to test. In addition, the problem will need either a correction (bug), a restart (transient failure like bad DDR access, memory corruption) or a new deployment (hardware failure, power failure). For those kind of error, it is much more efficient to let crash and use the restart policy available with OTP. rather than put check everywhere and don't know what to do. Last point, it is also possible to use the let it crash policy with the first kind of error as you did, but it may be less readable.

Comment: thanks you Pascal i think that i understand this. But just in my precedent example:the rex server spawn a new process worker and monitors it, is this the concept of supervisor and worker tree or not ? if not can you give me just a little example of this ?

Comment: There is a very good and complete explanation here. If you are interested in Erlang, I recommend you this site. The first chapters are about syntax and data structures, you can go very fast, the 2 last third are about concurrency, OTP, program organization, tests and many features that are not obvious to catch by oneself. [learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors). It is a very good complement to Joe Armstrong book.

Comment: i had this book in pdf format i will read it carrefully,i have three e-book that are very important for erlang learning:the Joe's book, learnyousomeerlangforgreatgood and francesco cesarini's erlang programming book so thank you amigo i will meet you in the next post.